# Rails helper that to check conditional

Tags: ruby-on-rails, helper

I would like to know if checking conditions for the view is the correct use of helper.

Let's look at a contrived exmaple:

**helper**

```
def free_to_subscribe(product)
  current_user.active_member? && product.on_discount?
end
```

**view**

```
...
<% elsif free_to_subscribe(product) %>
  Free to subscribe!
<% end %>
...
```

I thought helpers needed return something to display in the view. Helpers that return boolean seem like a bit of a smell. Any ideas?

Comment: works for me. Though as it' returns a boolean, I'd add a question mark to the end of the name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I personally would have put it in a model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  def free_to_subscribe?(product)
    active_member? && product.on_discount?
  end
end
```

Then the view would look like this:

```
...
<% elsif current_user.free_to_subscribe(product) %>
  Free to subscribe!
<% end %>
...
```

It's slightly more code in the view but otherwise it's like you're arbitrarily choosing to stick certain logic in helpers with no real reason, in my view.